# How to use ng-repeat such that it shows two cards in an row?

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="a in result.products">
 <img style="margin-top:-15px;height: 146px;width: 109.9%;margin-left: -16px;" src="./img/Final1.jpg">
  <p style="font-weight:bold;">
   {{a.name}}
  </p>
  <p style="font-weight:bold;">
   {{a.display_price}}
  </p>
</div>
```

I have created a list of cards using ng-repeat. Now i want to display first and second card in first row, third and fourth card in second row and so on.

Comment: Do you use Bootstrap or another grid-based framework?

Comment: please provide your html

Comment: i'm doing it in ionic framework

Comment: i have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use containers that take up half the screen. For instance, if you're using bootstrap, use `col-xs-6`.

If you need a container per row, then one way to do it is by using a loop that iterates length/2 over the array, and within this loop, display item `i*2` and `i*2 + 1`.

Unfortunately, you can't really iterate `n` times using `ng-repeat`, but only over an array. So you would need a helper function that returns an array of indices. What you could also do is using a conditional to check if the current item is even, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in myarray track by $index">
   <div ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">
      <div>{{myarray[$index]}}</div>
      <div ng-if="myarray.length < $index+1">{{myarray[$index+1]}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If this approach would lead to a lot of code duplication, because of similar html for item n*2 and item n*2+1, you could consider using a simple template directive that takes the item as isolate scope.